# clojurescript unit testing recommendations

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, clojurescript, figwheel

Trying to setup basic unit testing with clojurescript.  Looked at:

https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Testing

In my `project.clj` file I have:

```
:cljsbuild {
            :builds [{:id "dev"
                      :source-paths ["src" "test"]
                      :figwheel { :on-jsload "my-proj.core/on-js-reload" }
                      :compiler {:main figreag.router
                                 :asset-path "js/compiled/out"
                                 :output-to "resources/public/js/compiled/my_proj.js"
                                 :output-dir "resources/public/js/compiled/out"
                                 :source-map-timestamp true }}
```

The main point is I add "test" into the `:source-paths`.

Then in: `test/my-proj/tests.cljs` I have:

```
(ns  ^:figwheel-always my-proj.tests
(deftest all-tests
  (run-tests 'my-proj.core-test)
  (run-tests 'my-proj.util-test))
```

Then in my REPL I do `(run-tests)`.  Is this the idiomatic way?  I am also using figwheel too, obviously.

Comment: This has the problem that edits to tests aren't cleanly picked up by the REPL.  Which kills tight iterations.  Likely have to kill REPL, do a `lein clean`, then restart the REPL for test changes to get picked up.  NOT FUN! :)  Redefining a test function is OK, but removing test functions doesn't work unless you unload the namespace.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Although you could also use `on-js-reload` callback to `(run-tests)` , right?